# Tips for starting career in Data Science Consulting

Tags: career

Now that I have my engineering degree with a specialization in finance & quantitative analysis, I plan to start my career in Data Science Consulting.

To develop my path a little, I took data science courses (some included in my engineering cursus, which I completed with others courses found on the internet), I carried out research on predictive problems during academic project and I did my end-of-studies internship as a data scientist.

The community seems to be the most active on this topic, so I'm posting this message to ask for advice and information, please.

Firstly, as my education does not match the job, do you have any certification, particularly useful for a Data Science consultant to advise me?

Secondly, what projects/career paths are available when going down this path?

Finally, a two-step question, what did you find particularly difficult during the exercise of this job? Do you have a final lesson to share with a junior who is going down this path?
Thank you !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.